# Apple Pay popup not showing with specific default shipping addresses

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I'm in France and trying to pop up Apple Pay sheet in my app.
When I set a France default shipping address in Settings, it works.
(And then I can switch to a US address)

When I set a US default shipping address in Settings, it works sometimes but often fails. An when it fails, the Apple Pay sheet simply doesn't show.
(`PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` instance and `PKPaymentRequest` instance are correct and not `nil`)

It's very odd...

Comment: The implied question is, "why doesn't it show up".  Can you improve this question with pertinent code and any lldb console output that might give a clue?  Somehow, conditions differ between the working and non-working cases.  When I see apparent randomness, my first thought is "race condition".

Comment: You're right, I just made a simple apple pay code, all in the main thread and it works. I'll investigate to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Found it !
It is unrelated to specific addresses!

Implementing this delegate method this way doesn't work

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                  didSelectShippingContact:(PKContact *)contact
                                completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus,
                                                     NSArray<PKShippingMethod *> * _Nonnull,
                                                     NSArray<PKPaymentSummaryItem *> * _Nonnull))completion{
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess, @[], _currentRequest.paymentSummaryItems);
}
```

(the `_currentRequest` is the `PKPaymentRequest` I used to popup the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` which is saved as a instance attribute)

I can't explain it but setting `PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusInvalidShippingPostalAddress` instead of `PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess` in the completion will work.
And setting a break point when we call the completion will also allow Apple Pay sheet to show.

But if you still wish to return `PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess` in the completion method, use it this way:

```
completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess, nil, _currentRequest.paymentSummaryItems);
```

Yes, setting a `nil` value to a `nonnull` specified parameter will work !